# TextBox select only works half the time

Tags: vb.net

I'm pulling my hair out over this one.  I have a subroutine that checks for a valid ToolID when the user leaves the textbox.  If it is valid it adds it to a Datatable and then updates a DataGridView from the datatable.  When all is done I want the textbox to either be empty or the text in the box to be selected so the user can just start typing again.  Trying to set the the text to "" was causing problems, even when removing and adding the handler so selecting all text is a perfectly satisfactory alternative.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub TxtBrochsteins_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBrochsteinsID.Leave
    If txtBrochsteinsID.Text = "" Then
        txtBrochsteinsID.Select(0, txtBrochsteinsID.Text.Length)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim hdr As Object, msg As Object
    dt = GetDataTable("GetRepair_x_BrochsteinsID",
                      {New cParameters(ParamName:="@BrochsteinsID", Value:=txtBrochsteinsID.Text, SqlType:=SqlDbType.NVarChar)}
                     )
    ' Brochsteins ID is not a valid ID
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        hdr = "Invalid Brochsteins ID"
        msg = txtBrochsteinsID.Text + " is not a valid Brochsteins ID." & vbCrLf & "Please enter a valid ID."
        MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, hdr)
        txtBrochsteinsID.Select(0, txtBrochsteinsID.Text.Length)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Check that Brochsteins ID is already assigned to a toolbox
    If dt.Rows(0)("ToolStatus") <> Shop Then
        hdr = "Illegal Brochsteins ID Assignment"
        msg = txtBrochsteinsID.Text & " is already assigned to " & dt.Rows(0)("ToolboxDesc") & vbCrLf &
              "Please enter a different Brochsteins ID or Return this ID to the Tool Room first."
        MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, hdr)
        txtBrochsteinsID.Select(0, txtBrochsteinsID.Text.Length)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    DtTools_Add(dt)
    txtBrochsteinsID.Select(0, txtBrochsteinsID.Text.Length)
End Sub
```

The problem is it only works every other time.  I've checked the call stack in both cases and it is always the same, so I'm not darting off somewhere unexpected.  That strikes me as odd behavior because it should either always work or never work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your setting the selection in a few potential places, is it a specific occurrence that's not working as expected?  Also wonder if you might be better served using the Textbox validated event which has a bit of inbuilt control on what happens on invalid entry

Comment: Not sure if this related to your issue but you could use the `SelectAll` method since you're selecting the whole textbox contents.

Comment: You need to _reselect_ the control. Call `txtBrochsteinsID.Focus()` or `txtBrochsteinsID.Select()` before `Exit Sub`. As mentioned, handle the `Validating` event instead and `.SelectAll` is the right method.

Comment: I had tried using Validating, I read on here somewhere that Validating is better than Leave, but I got another weird behavior.  When I enter a value and hit tab, nothing happens.  Or at least nothing that fires the handler.  I have to hit tab twice to get the handler to fire.  Any idea what I have done to cause that behavior?

Comment: `If txtBrochsteinsID.Text = "" Then txtBrochsteinsID.Select(0, txtBrochsteinsID.Text.Length)` seems pointless